# Multiple-step OLEDB operation generated errors

Tags: sql-server, database, vbscript

I'm in need of getting all table names in a database.
I keep ending with the error

> operation is not allowed when the object is closed

I've searched around and found a lot saying they should add `SET NOCOUNT ON` or `Set objRecords = objRecords.NextRecordset()` which results in the error:

> multiple-step ole db operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if availabe. No Work was done

This is where I'm stuck whatever I'm doing I shift between these errors.

The query I'm trying to do

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON Use {Database} SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_CATALOG='{Database}'
```

My connection string `"Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source={Server}; Initial Catalog={Database}; User ID={Login}; Password={Password};"`

My SQL server is on a Windows Server 2012.

The function I get the error in:

```vb
Function LoadTableData()
  Dim objSqlConnection : Set objSqlConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Dim objRecords : Set objRecords = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

  objSqlConnection.Open ReplaceInfo()
  Dim ReplacedText : ReplacedText = Replace(SelectAllDatabaseTables, "{Database}", SelectedDatabase)

  objRecords.Open ReplacedText, objSqlConnection, 3, 3

  Set objRecords = objRecords.NextRecordset()
  Do While Not objRecords.EOF
    alert("Test")
    objRecords.MoveNext()
  Loop
End Function
```

For what I can see there shouldn't be a problem but I think it's something to do with the query as I can do a `SELECT * FROM {Database}` without any issues.

Comment: Try commenting out this line: `Set objRecords = objRecords.NextRecordset()`.  I believe it is the source of your `operation is not allowed when the object is closed` error.

Comment: Just commented it out and get the `operation is not allowed when the object is closed`

Comment: when You use SET NOCOUNT ON in query that means You get only one recordset and Set objRecords = objRecords.NextRecordset() closes current RS - oblect is closed

Comment: The "Multi Step Operation" is due to the query. You need `GO` between `USE database-name` and other statements or end each separate statement with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure how this fixed it but I moved the USE {DATABASE} out of the query and executed it on the connection instead which fixed my issues